# How do I configure django settings to send email to Ibm lotus Notes

Tags: python, django, email, lotus-notes

I have an html page with a form where I collect some data like mail_sender, mesage_to_send, subject etc.

When a user click on a button that information is submitted to a views.py function:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def register_new_request(request):
        email_person = request.POST.get('email_person', False)
        send_mail('Test', 'Here is the message.', email_person,['tosomeone@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

How i configure in my settings.py to send email to lotus notes via that function?

After some research i found that are some variables that need to be configured like :

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = ''
EMAIL_PORT = ''
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
```

Can tell me someone how exactly should look that variables? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

django.core.email sends SMTP mail. There is absolutely nothing special about sending SMTP email to Lotus Notes users. It looks exactly like sending email to any other email user on the Internet.

If your real question is about sending to a Lotus Notes user from within that user's internal network, presumably by submitting your SMTP message directly to a Lotus Domino server, then you need to talk to the administrator(s) responsible for the servers and find out (a) if SMTP is enabled on at least one internal Domino server, (b) what host and port to use to connect via SMTP to the Domino server, (c) is SSL/TLS supported or required for the SMTP connection to the Domino server (d) whether authentication is required, and if yes what user name and password your code should use.